# Create CodeIgniter-Like routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to reproduce codeigniter type routes in larvel. For example the route `'about/directions'` would load the about controller and the directions method, while the route `'about/directions/fastest'` would call the method with the parameter `'fastest'`.

The closest I've come so far is using `Route::group` in the following manner:

```
Route::group( ['prefix'=>'about'], function()
{
    Route::get( 'directions/{optional?}', 'about@directions' );
});
```

Which works but still requires me to manually insert every route possible on every controller. I also tried the `Route::controller()` method. This seems closer but requires me to prepend my method names with 'get' or 'post' and can't seem to have one method responding to all the HTTP verbs.

So is it possible to use `Route::controller` and make one method respond to all verbs? Or is there another solution to make routing work in this fashion?

### [edit]

After some additional poking around I found I can use a combination of `Route::controller` and `missingMethod()` as follows:

```
public function missingMethod( $params )
{
   call_user_func_array( [$this, array_shift($params)], $params );
}
```

but I'm still wondering if there's a baked in way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Route::controller('about', 'AboutController')` to wire up a controller.

Within the controller you add methods prefixed with an HTTP verb (get, post, put, delete).  There are very few reasons why you'd want to use the same code for both GET and POST (let alone PUT, PATCH, DELETE, and OPTIONS too) - generally this reveals some bad design - but if you really do then you can use the `any` prefix for actions that respond to any verb...

```php
class AboutController extends BaseController {
    public function anyDirections($approach = 'fastest')
    {
        // Build and return a Response
    }
}
```

But consider why you are needing POST - are you really changing the state of your directions (a change to the database), or are you hiding user input from the query string?  If you are changing state, why can you not redirect them back after the changes have been saved?  If you're just hiding from the query string - why?

Comment: honestly having to add 'get' before everyone one of my method names is just annoying me; I don't really need them to respond to multiple methods. It makes them harder to find/read in the IDE. I'm finding a lot of laravel's "features" more of an impediment then a help thus far. While CI's routing is limited, it also 'just works' without any configuration which is frustrating me here.

Comment: If CodeIgniter are good enough (for you), why force yourselves?

Comment: @crynobone because while I like the simplicity of CI's routing, most of the rest of the framework has serious flaws

Answer (score 0):

What about using a route filter and passing it to a controller:

```
Route::get('about/{slug}', 'PageController@showAbout')->where('slug', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Steps:

1. route matched to either post or get request
2. used web/controllerName/MethodName/Parameter1/parameter2 .. 
   all parameters received in an array as $params. web/ is used like a route 
   prefix. If no method is passed it will call index method
3. explode the parameter
4. called the controller with method and paramteres passed
5. parameters are matched for regex allowing alphanumeric and slash (url)
6. passed through guest middleware

created controller as mentioned below:

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index($param1,$param2,$param3)
    {
         return 'index'.$param1.$param2.$param3;
    }    
}



Route::match(['get','post'],'/web/{controller}/{method?}/{params?}', 
function ($controller, $method='index', $params=array()) {    

    $params = explode('/', $params);

    $controller = app()->make("\App\Http\Controllers\\". 
    ucwords($controller).'Controller' );


    return $controller->callAction($method, $params);

})->where('params', '[A-Za-z0-9/]+')->middleware('guest');
```